# Custom progress bar is not working and app is crashing

Tags: android, progressdialog

When I'm trying to use a custom progress bar it is not showing the progress bar, and after some time the application is crashing.

Code:

```java
public class RegistrationScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    CustomProgressDialog customdialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

    }@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.register_submit_btn:
            showProgress();
        }

        private void showProgress() {
            customdialog = new CustomProgressDialog(RegistrationScreen.this);
            customdialog.setTitle("Please Wait a Movement...");
            customdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            customdialog.setCancelable(false);
            customdialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is error??

Comment: Please add code of you CustomProgressDialog class and error log also.

Comment: Which library you are using for CustomProgressDialog?

Comment: paste your logcat here